# Open and close a form with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have added 4 selections to a dropdown menu to load the designated form, however, when clicking on the following selection the previous form is still visible. I need to be able to transition between forms and not load the next selection on top of the previous one.

HTML forms:

```
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          I'm a dropdown button
                        </button>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<a class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="form1btn">form1btn</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="form2btn">form2btn</a>

                        <form id="form1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="formGroupExampleInput"> I'm form 1</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                        </div>
                        </form>

                        <form id="form2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="formGroupExampleInput"> I'm form 2</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
                        </div>
                        </form>
```

jquery buttons and hide/show:

```
    $('#form1').hide()
$('#form2').hide()
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1btn').click(function(){
    $('#form1').toggle();
    });

$('#form2btn').click(function(){
    $('#form2').toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: You should be able to hide all forms using `$('form').hide();` so just call that before each `.show()`. - -  `when clicking a form in the drop-down menu` ...sounds weird however, usually a dropdown is part of a form, not the other way around

Comment: I have the forms hidden. When trying to transition between one form to the next they continue to display above one another. I want the previous one to hide after selecting the next option in the drop-down menu

Comment: Ok, so add an `.on("change", ...)` handler to the dropdown, and in there, hide all forms then show the selected one. Also, please create a [mre] in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure where to add that in to the form. Do you mean to place it above the form selections that are hidden? What kind of function would be added to the handler? Thanks for your help, I added my html into the original post.

Comment: Again, please create a [mre], emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: I have made a minimal reproducible example. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see what I wrote in my first comment? It's the only thing that was missing: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h9gyvctk/ (btw, each `id` is supposed to be unique; so even if just one form is visible at a time, clicking a label to activate the input won't work properly if multiple inputs have the same id across forms.)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this.Based on the current form that you want to display,you can hide all other form .this will save you the time of checking on whether certain form is being displayed or not

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#residentialbtn').click(function()
     $('#commercialform').hide()
     $('#corporateform').hide()
    $('#hybridform').hide()
    $('#residentialform').show();
})
```

Comment: Can I get some more information? I replaced my original code with what you wrote and had issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly.

```
$('#form1').hide()
$('#form2').hide()
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form1btn').click(function(){
$('#form1').toggle();
   $('#form2').hide()
});

$('#form2btn').click(function()
$('#form2').toggle();
 $('#form1').hide()
});

});
```